# Error en listado Array + Json

Tags: php, ajax, json

Estoy tratando de hacer un listado de productos para obteniendo los datos a través de `ajax` y `ajax`. Pero el problema esta en que no me trae todos los datos del listado que necesito mostrar, solo me muestra una `A`.

```
Tabla  Artículos

nombre        |    cateId
==========================
Tornillos     |    2
Bujes         |    3
Aros          |    1
```

Ajax

```
<div id="prueba"></div>

</script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
document.getElementById("prueba").innerHTML = myObj[2];
}
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "datos.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
</script>
```

datos.php

```
<?php
try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pruebas', 'root', 'pass');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM articulos");
while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
$myArr[] = $row['nombre']['cateId'];
}

$myJSON = json_encode($myArr);

echo $myJSON;
?>
```

Comment: Estructura bien el array en el while $myArr["nombre"]=$row["nombre"]; $myArr["cateId"]=$row["cateId"]; para recoger los datos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando usas PDO, puedes valerte del [*fetch style*  `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php) para obtener los resultados como un array asociativo. De ese modo el array se llenará de una forma natural, por ejemplo:

```
<?php
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pruebas', 'root', 'pass');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM articulos");
while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $myArr[] = $row;
}

$myJSON = json_encode($myArr);
echo $myJSON;
?>
```

En el código de más arriba, `$row` será en cada iteracción del `while` una fila completa asociativa con los nombres de columna => datos.

Si solamente necesitas las columnas `nombre` y `cateId`, entonces recomiendo que lo especifiques en el `SELECT`, de ese modo evitar traer datos que no vas a usar en ese contexto: `SELECT nombre, cateId FROM articulos`

---

> #### Nota sobre PDO y la seguridad
>
> Te recomiendo que apagues las preparaciones emuladas en tu conexión PDO haciendo lo siguiente debajo
>   de la línea: `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,
>   PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`:
>
> ```
> $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
> ```
>
> En PDO las preparaciones emuladas se establecen por defecto en `TRUE`,
>   y con esta funcionalidad encendida en algunos escenarios te pueden
>   colar inyecciones SQL más fácilmente ([ver esta pregunta de SO en
>   inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10113562/5587982)).

Comment: Gracias Cedaro por la info de seguridad y por responder, ahora me trae los datos, pero también tenia que modificar esto: `document.getElementById("prueba").innerHTML = myObj[2];` de ajax. Tambien hice esto: `$myArr[] = $row['nombre'];` `$myArr[] = $row['cateId'].'<br>';` y como resultado obtengo esto: `Soldador de Estaño,1
,PC,2 ,Aros,2` con sus respectivos saltos de linea, pero no se porque me pone las `comas`. Respecto a `SELECT`, lo deje para que seleccione todo porque no se que va a querer el cliente, lo que estoy haciendo es a modo de prueba.

Comment: Yo no pondría el `<br>` ahí. Devolvería los datos lo más naturalmente posible, dándoles formato en el destino. Por ejemplo, en el cliente, leyendo los datos dentro de un bucle y agregando los saltos de línea.  Generalmente la consulta devolverá varias filas, entonces en Javascript puedes concatenar la lectura en una variable dentro de un bucle y fuera del bucle actualizar el contenedor con `innerHTML` o mejor con `textContent`.

Comment: En JS la lectura sería más o menos así: `var htmlOutput=""; myObj.forEach(function(item){
    htmlOutput +=item.nombre + "-"+ item.cateId + "<br />";
}); document.getElementById("prueba").innerHTML = htmlOutput;`

Comment: Perdón, se muy poco de ajax y json. Estuve mirando [este](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp) tutorial y mas o menos lo adapte como para poder obtener una lista de los productos, precios, etc.. Pido disculpas por la falta de conocimiento. Pero gracias por la ayuda

Comment: No es por decepcionarte, pero W3Schools ha sido muy criticada en la comunidad de programadores, porque en muchos de sus tutoriales enseña malas prácticas. Quizá no es el caso aquí, pero lo que se recomienda es que trates de aprender mejor de los ejemplos que muestra la documentación oficial: Manual de PHP, si es HTML/Javascript puedes usar Mozilla Developper NetWork, y así según el lenguaje es mejor que te refieras primero a las fuentes oficiales. Y bueno por aquí cuando vemos alguna mala práctica solemos indicarlo (somos 4 ó 5 que siempre damos la cantaleta con eso pero algo es algo).

Comment: No sabia eso, bueno, voy a recurrir directamente al manual, y puede que no este errado, llevo varios días tratando de solucionar algo que ya hice tantas modificaciones que me he perdido. Por eso recurrí aquí, je,

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88643/discussion-between-stn-and-a-cedano).

Comment: Ahi pude cambiarlo el script, pero no me trae ningun dato: `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "datos.php");
xhr.onload = function () {
 if (xhr.status == 200) {
  var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  var htmlOutput="";
  xhr.forEach(function(item){
   htmlOutput +=item.nombre + "-"+ item.cateId + "<br>";
   });
   document.getElementById("prueba").innerHTML = htmlOutput;
 
} else {
 console.log("Error: "+xhr.status);
}
}
xhr.send();`

Comment: Pero ¿qué comportamiento tiene? ¿Muestra error en la consola? Intenta mostrar lo que trae la petición poniendo esto `console.log(xhr.responseText);` Supongo que sabes mirar en la consola.

Comment: Ya lo he arreglado, aunque la verdad es que no se que hice, pero bueno, funciono: `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "datos.php");
xhr.onload = function () {
 if (xhr.status == 200) {
  var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  var template = "";
  json.map(function(item){
   template += item.nombre + " - "+ item.cateId + "<br>";
   });
   document.getElementById("prueba").innerHTML = template;
 } else {
  console.log("Error: "+xhr.status);
 }
}
xhr.send();`, Así quedo. Ahora me queda ingresar el diseño, pero bueno, esa es la parte mas simple, je

Comment: Muchas gracias Cedano!